# Intersection of Shapefiles, clean borders

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to create a shapefile of the state of zip codes (in this example, I pick Virginia). However, the zip codes do not line up exactly to the state borders. So I run the following query to get a shapefile of the zip codes for the given state.

```
SELECT uszips.geoid10, uszips.geom FROM uszips,va_shp
WHERE ST_Intersection(uszips.geom, va_shp.geom) 
GROUP BY uszips.geoid10, uszips.geom
```

However, when I checked the shapefile, it looks like this:
[image]

When the state of Virginia looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can return the shapefile with the zip code geom truncated to match the exact borders of the state?

Comment: Some ZIP codes span multiple states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ST_Intersects and ST_Intersection are two different things. The former is a true/false check, and the latter returns the intersection. In your query, you're returning the whole geometry, rather than the intersected geometry, when the intersected geometry is not null. Not an error, but not what you want.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE zips AS 
SELECT geoid10, geom FROM (
    SELECT uszips.geoid10, (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(uszips.geom, va_shp.geom))).geom
    FROM uszips,va_shp
    WHERE ST_Intersects(uszips.geom, va_shp.geom)
) t 
WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_Polygon';
```

Comment: Hrmm, I tried running the query and everything looks normal except for this output: `Dumping: XXUnknown WKB type (7) for record 110`. I tried opening the shape file and it's empty. Not sure what happened.

Comment: I think 7 is GeometryCollection. It's possible the output is mixed (e.g. Polygons and collections of Polygons.) I've added an update that might help, by dumping any multi- geometries or collections. If you provide a download link I could test it.

Comment: No luck. The file still comes up empty. I've linked the file for your convenience; the zip file can be found [here](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2014/layers.cgi) while the Virginia file can be found [here](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2013-state-virginia-current-county-subdivision-state-based)

Comment: I got it to work, but I had to filter out all the non-polygon results. Because some neighbouring zip areas touch the state boundary only on an edge or a point, you'll get degenerate geometries (lines and points) in the output. What are you actually using to create the shapefile?

Comment: What do you mean? I download the files from the US census and then upload them using shp2pgsql-gui and then I attempt to run the following query.

Comment: Your question says your'e trying to create a shapefile. And your comment says "the file still comes up empty." How are you trying to create it?

Comment: Ooh I run the query through the terminal using pgsql2shp

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to create a table with only polygons. If you'd like to talk more about it we can go to chat, but it should work as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27160/discussion-between-minh-mai-and-rob-skelly).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Virginia shapefile to [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) the Zip Code shapefile. Note: This will cut the polygons and you will not have the exact geometry of each zip code area.

Comment: Is there a clip feature in postGIS? Looking through documentation and can't find anything similar ( I may have missed it)

Comment: ST_Intersection clips http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html. Sometimes you can use http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Difference.html or http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html.